# ASP.NET DateTime Serialization in QueryString vs Body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I noticed `DateTime` objects are serialized differently for the same values between QueryString and Body. The underlying value is still the same correct value, however the serialized QueryString has a `DateTimeKind` of `Local`, whereas the Body is `Utc`.

#### Endpoint

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromQuery] DateTime queryDate, [FromBody] DateTime bodyDate)
{
  var result = new
  {
    queryDateKind = queryDate.Kind.ToString(),
    bodyDateKind = bodyDate.Kind.ToString()
  };

  return new ObjectResult(result);
}
```

#### Request

```
POST /api/values?queryDate=2019-05-12T00%3A00%3A00.000Z HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
"2019-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
```

#### Response

```
{
    "queryDateKind": "Local",
    "bodyDateKind": "Utc"
}
```

Any idea why this is? Is there perhaps a setting to always serialize to the same `DateTimeKind`?

Preferably I wouldn't want to use `ToUniversalTime()` or `ToLocalTime()` everywhere, nor use any custom `IModelBinder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that's the way it is, have a look at this answer - [Passing UTC DateTime to Web API HttpGet Method results in local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581138/passing-utc-datetime-to-web-api-httpget-method-results-in-local-time)

It's related to how query string parameters and message bodies are treated differently, Model binding vs parameter binding.

You will have to either call `.ToUniversalTime()` or implement your own model binder to get around this.

Comment: That's not entirely true. You can simply configure the JSON formatter to achieve the desired result. Something like: `services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local);`

Comment: @haim770 That setting will only affect the Model Binding from the Message Body. It has no affect on parameter binding.But yes, if he always wants Local time then that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using **DateTimeOffset** in the API model will avoid unwanted timezone conversions.  See [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66994521/358006).

Comment: This only works if using `AutoMapper`. See linked answer.